# From complex JSON to dictionaries

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net

I have been experimenting with JSON.net, I have a complex JSON file. I may not use sequential loops to search my data, so I thought I needed to use dictionaries so can enter the key I need and get the related object.

I have been able to deserialize the json to a dictionary, but this is only from the first node. I will first show u the JSON before i continue (It's quite a lot of data so i made it shorter), there is an error in the json , but you get the idea of the JSON

```
{
    "response": {
        "dsCompanyContract": {
            "dsCompanyContract": {
                "ttEmployee": [
                    {
                        "empUID": 467775,
                        "empNameFirst": "Name1",
                        "empNameLast": "lastname",
                        "empFunction": "TECHNICUS AUTOTECHNIEK",
                        "ttContract": [
                            {
                                "UID": 1,
                                "empUID": 467775,
                                "refkey": "1_1808630",
                                "datStart": "2013-05-27",
                                "datStop": "2013-05-31",
                                "regime": 1,
                                "state": "CONTRACTED",
                                "ttScheduleDay": [
                                    {
                                        "ContractUID": 1,
                                        "dat": "2013-05-27",
                                        "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-27T08:00:00.000",
                                        "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-27T17:00:00.000",
                                        "duration": 8
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ContractUID": 1,
                                        "dat": "2013-05-28",
                                        "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-28T08:00:00.000",
                                        "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-28T17:00:00.000",
                                        "duration": 8
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ContractUID": 1,
                                        "dat": "2013-05-29",
                                        "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-29T08:00:00.000",
                                        "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-29T17:00:00.000",
                                        "duration": 8
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ContractUID": 1,
                                        "dat": "2013-05-30",
                                        "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-30T08:00:00.000",
                                        "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-30T17:00:00.000",
                                        "duration": 8
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "ContractUID": 1,
                                        "dat": "2013-05-31",
                                        "dateTimeStart": "2013-05-31T08:00:00.000",
                                        "dateTimeStop": "2013-05-31T16:00:00.000",
                                        "duration": 7
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                            ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to accomplish is to make a dictionary of:

- All ttEmployees (with key: empUID)
- All ttContracts within the ttEmployee (with key: UID)
- All ttScheduleDays within the ttContracts (with key: dat)

I have been able to do this but I was looping through all my object within a list and then manually adding them into the library. I was wondering how I could do this faster? 
At this moment i'm using:

```
  obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, Response>>(
        newFormatJSON, new JsonConverter[] { new JSONDictionaryConverter() });
```

This makes a dictionary of the rootelement, from here on i start looping through the data and adding the objects to the selfmade - dictionaries

The problem with JSON.net I find examples of how to convert to a dictionary, but not with a complex JSON. I first have to skip several nodes before it makes the dictionary.

Any help would be appreciated, I will update when needed / requested.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you consider using [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/)? It might be relevant...

Comment: I don't get something. Why dictionaries? Why not define proper models?

Comment: Easier to find the right objects then going through the models... MongoDb, never worked with, will give it a look.